# Updating element position using ENTER_FRAME event

Tags: actionscript-3

I have an issue in simple arkanoid game in updating paddle position, I am using following listener to react:

```
paddle.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, movePaddle)
```

when `movePaddle()` function is defined in `Main` everything is working just fine, but when I refactored code and putted `movePaddle()` functions into `Paddle` class and changed listener into:

```
paddle.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, paddle.movePaddle)
```

The result is paddle changing position every frame between the desired one, and some other value

Below `movePaddle()` function:

```
public function movePaddle(event:Event):void
{
    // DEBUG
    trace(this.x);
    trace(this.y);

    this.x = mouseX - this.width / 2;

    if(mouseX < this.width / 2)
    {
        this.x = 0;
    }

    // To much to right
    if(this.x >= stage.stageWidth - this.width)
    {
        // To much to left
        this.x = stage.stageWidth - this.width;
    }
}
```

Second question:
Is using `ENTER_FRAME` event good in terms of optimalisation for games ?

Comment: Second question: ENTER_FRAME is fine, but you could also use a timer with an interval of 0. mouseX is in local coordinates (relative to `paddle`'s top left corner in this case), which is probably what's messing up the movement. You can call localToGlobal to convert mouseX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Cameron mentioned, if you move `movePaddle()` to the `Paddle` class itself, `mouseX` and `mouseY` will refer to the mouse position within the Paddle MovieClip. That is, if the Paddle is at 50,50 on the stage, and the mouse is at 100, 100 on the stage, the mouse coordinates you will receive will be 50,50.

A safer option is to use the `mouseX` and `mouseY` values given by the `Stage`:

```
public function movePaddle(event:Event):void
{
    if(stage != null)
    {
        x = stage.mouseX - width / 2;

        if(stage.mouseX < width / 2)
        {
            this.x = 0;
        }

        // To much to right
        if(x >= stage.stageWidth - width)
        {
            // To much to left
            x = stage.stageWidth - width;
        }
    }
}
```

Another thing I would do is rather than having this line in the `Main` class:

```
paddle.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, paddle.movePaddle);
```

I would instead put that in `Paddle`'s constructor like so:

```
public function Paddle()
{
    addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, movePaddle);
}
```

As for performance of `ENTER_FRAME`, this is fine however in a properly structured game I would have a single `ENTER_FRAME` handler which loops over an Array of game entities and them updates them all by calling a method on each.